# How to prevent NSTableView to call delegate function?

Tags: swift, cocoa, notifications, delegates, tableview

I have two tableviews, from which tableview1 gets its data from NSArrayController. Tableview2 gets it´s data from tableview delegate like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableview2: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

        if tableview2 == self.tableview2 {

            if let cellView = tableView.make(withIdentifier: (tableColumn?.identifier)!, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView {
               let numbers = array[row]
               if tableColumn?.identifier == "cell" {
                   cellView.textField?.stringValue = "\(numbers.number)"

                   return cellView
               }
            }
        }
        return nil
}
```

If I reload the data from tabeleview1, the above tableview function gets called and returns nil. So tableview1 is always empty. I could of course delete tableview1´s delegate outlet, but I need it for `tableViewSelectionDidChange()` function.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you reload tableView1, it will call viewForTableColumn. If you do not want that, don't call reloadData on tableView1. If you are returning nil, how is that your tableview1 is rendered on screen?

Comment: @adev I´m not calling reloadData on tableview1. Tableview1 is bound to an array [NSObejct] via NSArrayController. When I update the array, tableview1 shows empty rows. The number of rows in tableview1 correspond to the number of items in the array. Also there are the right values in tableview1 (I can see it in the console). So tableview1 is populated with the right number of rows and even with the right values. But the cells in the tableview are visually empty.

Comment: Why do you ask the same question repeatedly?  You asked the exactly same question some 20 hours ago.

Comment: @ElTomato because there was a comment that apparently was some code missing. so i reestablished the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a cell view for every table view. Set the values of the controls of table view 2.

```
func tableView(_ tableview2: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    if let cellView = tableView.make(withIdentifier: (tableColumn?.identifier)!, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView {
        if tableview2 == self.tableview2 {
            if tableColumn?.identifier == "cell" {
                let numbers = array[row]
                cellView.textField?.stringValue = "\(numbers.number)"
            }
        return cellView
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: The logic of this solution can´t be denied. Also I never would have come to this. This really helped me a lot. Thanks!